# How to iterate through multiple datasets with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, multiple-conditions

I am trying to iterate through multiple datasets with a calculation containing multiple conditions, but I receive an error message. I can iterate through multiple lists, but it doesn't seem to work for dataframes.

I have divided a huge dataset (originally from an HDF5 file) into smaller datasets with the same columns, but for different building types. Now I want to iterate through each dataset to do the same calculation. The calculation includes multiple coditions too.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

# Multiple datasets:

d1 = {'apples1': [45,2,15,0,39,6,12,7,86,24],
      'feathers1': [2,1,0,3,4,2,2,1,0,1]}
a = DataFrame(d1,columns=['apples1','feathers1'])

d2 = {'apples2': [2,52,1,27,1,5,1,28,2],
      'feathers2': [4,2,1,1,0,1,2,1,4]}
b = DataFrame(d2,columns=['apples2','feathers2'])

d3 = {'apples3': [12,5,1,23,1],
      'feathers3': [4,4,1,1,1]}
c = DataFrame(d3,columns=['apples3','feathers3'])

d4 = {'apples4': [82,53,17,28,10,5,16],
      'feathers4': [0,5,1,3,1,2,4]}
d = DataFrame(d3,columns=['apples4','feathers4'])

# Calculation iteration through all datasets:

A = []
B = []

for df in (a,b,c,d):    
    if ((df == a) | (df == b)).any(axis=1):
        k = 1
        A.append(k)
    elif ((df == c) | (df == d)).any(axis=1):
        k = 2
        B.append(k)
```

If the dataframe (df) is either **a OR b**, then perform the following calculation for these datasets; or alternatively if the dataset is either **c OR d**, do the other calculation instead for those datasets.
But, I receive the following **ValueError** message:

```py
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: `((df == a) | (df == b)).any(axis=1)` yields a series of boolean values with `length` equals to the number of rows you have. e.g. if you had 4 rows, that could evaluate to `True, False, True, True`. Now, how do you interpret `if [True, False, True, True]`? It's Likely  that you want `((df == a) | (df == b)).any(axis=1).any()`

Comment: Hi @rafaelc! When I do what you suggested, I receive another error message: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: That's because you have different column names. How do you compare dataframes with different labels (index or columns)? ;)

Comment: This looks like a weird design and looks like an XY Problem. If I were you, I'd post your actual problem, i.e. what you are actually trying to achieve rather than _how to fix this specific solution_ of yours !

Comment: @rafaelc Do you suggest that I should change the column names to all identical names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
for df in (a,b,c,d):    
    if df.equals(a) or df.equals(b):
        k = 1
        A.append(k)
    elif df.equals(c) or df.equals(d):
        k = 2
        B.append(k)
```

equals() requires that the elements have the same dtype as their respective elements in the other Series or DataFrame. However, the column labels do not need to have the same type, as long as they are still considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this Problem before and tried to sort the index before Comparaison, try to change the Implementation like this:

```
A = []
B = []

for df in (a,b,c,d):
    if ((df.sort_index(inplace=True) == a.sort_index(inplace=True)) | (df.sort_index(inplace=True) == b.sort_index(inplace=True))):
        k = 1
        A.append(k)
    elif ((df.sort_index(inplace=True) == c.sort_index(inplace=True)) | (df.sort_index(inplace=True) == d.sort_index(inplace=True))):
        k = 2
        B.append(k)
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it seems to work halfway. No error messages, but it only seems to pick up the one condition since the output is: `[1, 1, 1, 1] [ ] ` and the expected answer should be `[1, 1] [2, 2] `

Comment: that's because the b, c and d are actually the same. try to change the values so that b, c and d doesnt have the same values